# How to get facebook friends recent activities

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get the recent activities of my facebook friends per day basis. I mean to say can i get my facebook friends wall? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can... all you have to do is query the graph api like this :

`https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/feed`

You will have to request the `read_stream` permission from the user in order to gain access to this data.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) is some information about permissions.
[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is some information about using the graph api.

**EDIT:**
Apologies, you can not retrieve information from a friends feed.  What you will have to do is request offline access from your users and only then will you be able to retrieve data from that users feed in order to give it to another user.

Comment: I have already give the offline_access permission. And i want to access my friends feed in facebook not my feed..Is it possible??

Comment: no - you have to request offline_access from ALL your users and only then can you supply the user with his friends feed - but the friend has to have also authorized offline_access... It is possible - but not very feasible...

Comment: I don't get you. I am getting my friend list with detail of each friend. Now how do i request offline_access from a particular friend?

Comment: you can not... you cant retrieve information about users that have not authorized your app... this is why i said it is not really feasible... because you will only be able to retrieve information about users that have authorized your app...

Answer (score 0):

I never used the Below solution,But I am sure there's Way to do this using **[FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)**

You will have to write a Query to GRAPH API and Using HTTP GET and you will get the data in JSON format,something like this not Completely sure but check the link FQL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+activities+FROM+user+WHERE+uid1=Friend'sID&access_token
```

from the **[USER](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)** table.

Hope you will get the solution,And If you try let my know your experience.